# Clients can no longer connect to the internet when on our VPN

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2016

I set up Routing and Remote Access the other day and when I connect to the server remotely, I am no longer able to connect to anything on the internet. I can only connect to resources on the remote network.

I assumed that my client uses a new default route and the article [You Cannot Connect to the Internet After You Connect to a VPN Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317025/you-cannot-connect-to-the-internet-after-you-connect-to-a-vpn-server) confirmed this. The article also provided a solution, which I tried and which solved the problem.

However, is there something I can do on the *server-side* to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Check for a setting that will allow Split-Tunneling.  That might be a vendor specific term, but it is an option in some VPN servers that controls the behavior you are referring to.  Be aware, though, that split tunneling is dangerous as the client computer can become a bridge between an unsafe network and your corporate network.

Comment: Do you want the remote users to get internet access without going through the VPN, or to have all internet traffic go through the VPN and then out?

Comment: @CoryKnutson The former. I want users to be able to access the VPN resources, but access the internet like they usually would.

Comment: Are the clients domain members?

Comment: @Twisty The users are, but the computers are not necessarily.